# How to make a legend with r-values and regression function in matplotlib (python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics

Following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

x=np.linspace(2.0, 3.0, num=100)*1e-5
y=np.linspace(2.0, 3.0, num=100)*1e3

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
predict_y = intercept + slope * x

plt.plot(x,y,'go')
plt.plot(x, predict_y, 'k-')
plt.legend(('data', 'line-regression'), 'upper left')
plt.autoscale(True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I can plot it, I can find the r-value, I can do a linear regression and show it on the plot. What I am too stupid to do is to write it on the graph. Maybe you can help?

So that the function and the r-value is shown as an own legend or in the legend or what you experts find best.

Kind regards! And ty very much in advance!

PS! If you know a better way to solve my problem, I would be very happy with it too :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
plt.legend(('data', 'line-regression r={}'.format(r_value)), 'best')
```

yields
[image]

Comment: Two questions left: is it possible to set the regression function in as well? And what does 'best' do? KR

Comment: 'best' tries to guess a suitable location for the legend (in which corner it should go without overlapping with the data in the plot)

Comment: To set the regression equation, just do `'y = {} + {}x'.format(np.round(intercept,2), np.round(slope,2))` or something along the lines.